# Connections obtained from Weblogic are set to autocommit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, weblogic, transactional

We have an application developed using Spring 3.1.1 and Hibernate 3.6.10, and uses Oracle 11g as database.

The application looks-up the datasource using JNDI, and uses a `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager`.

And spring configuration file contains:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/ds" 
  id="dataSource" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    ....
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

We use Tomcat in development machines, but the application is deployed on Weblogic 11 for production.

The problem is in Weblogic `datasource.log` file, the following message is logged:

```
<autoCommit=true,enabled=true,isXA=true,isJTS=false,vendorID=0,connUsed=false,doInit=false,'null',destroyed=false,poolname=life_rac,appname=null,moduleName=null,connectTime=45,dirtyIsolationLevel=false,initialIsolationLevel=2,infected=false,lastSuccessfulConnectionUse=1531636426817,secondsToTrustAnIdlePoolConnection=10,currentUser=java.lang.Exception
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnv.setup(ConnectionEnv.java:356)
    at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.reserveResource(ResourcePoolImpl.java:364)
    at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.reserveResource(ResourcePoolImpl.java:330)
    ...
```

Now we are worried about that `autoCommit=true` in the log messages, cause it seems that in some cases the first DML queries are committed when they shall not, especially when the Weblogic is stopped due to some problems (for example power-loss).

I shall mention that the data-source defined in Weblogic Server is a XA-Datasource.

Is there a way to change default configuration of `autoCommit` to `false`?

As we have just one database, and no other transactional resources, I believe we change can the datasource to a non-XA one, without any impact. Am I correct?

And we need to change the configuration so it works both on Weblogic and Tomcat (adding some configuration to Tomcat -such as adding a transaction manager- is okay).

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic Server 11g allows you to create and deploy a jdbc interceptor class. This [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13737/monitor.htm#JDBCA251) will help to write the class. Each time a connection is created, your interceptor will be called and you will be able to set the auto commit property to false.
This way is deprecated in 11g. 12c uses a Connection Initialization Callback.